# Can I overwrite a Unity app with a native android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a application build with Unity and now i'm thinking it would be better as a Native Android app.

The reason I wrote the app using the Unity framework was to be able to easily deploy to IOS as well. My numbers on IOS are really weak so I basically want to focus on Android.

I want to make it a Native app without making a new app like "My app 2" because of the existing user base.

My assumption is that if I have the keystore I can simply upload a new APK to overwrite the old one. Am i wrong? Is this even a possibility ? Are there any concerns with this approach? Is there anyone here who have done this successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an App with the **same package name** and sign it using the **same keys**, you can publish it as an update on Google Play if your `versionCode` is higher than your Unity apps versionCode.